# Auto suggestions for Docker container names with ohmyzsh

Tags: macos, zsh, docker

I'm migrating from Ubuntu to MacOS with my MacBook Pro (M2). I'm using ohmyzsh with the docker and docker-compose plugin. Docker has been installed with [Docker Desktop setup](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/).

All works fine except the autocompletion for the container names. If I type `docker start` and  <kbd>⮕Tab</kbd> it just shows me the files of my current directory, but not the list of available containers.

I'm expecting the autosuggestion to work here   and show me a list of all containers which could be started. This worked fine within Ubuntu.

I'd rather not run docker virtually or have to shell in to an already running container to get this functionality.

Is there a trick which I could use so the macOS command line has more completion options with zsh and docker for Mac?

Comment: So, just to be clear, this is just a problem with OMZ and *not* Docker?  In other words, does Docker work fine otherwise?

Comment: As far as I could test it yes. For example, docker can start a container with `docker start xyz`.

Comment: Sorry for the conflicting edits that Allan and I had. Hopefully this is clearer and works for everyone to start on an answer.

Comment: OhMyZsh (I personally stay away from it) is just a collection of Zsh scripts.  There’s nothing specific to macOS that is different from Ubuntu, Mint, or whatever.  You’ll likely get a faster, if not better answer from the OMZ community.  That said, I’d probably start with a clean re-install of the Docker plugin to ensure it’s configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines in your `.zshrc` file:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:docker:*' option-stacking yes
zstyle ':completion:*:*:docker-*:*' option-stacking yes
```

Source: https://github.com/felixr/docker-zsh-completion#docker-zsh-completion

Comment: Thats only for option-stacking like `-it`, not for my usecase :(